# How to add TextGeometry in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

How do i add text in three.js? I've tried this code but it produces an error of `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetX' of undefined`. How can I fix this?

Here is my [.json file](https://ufile.io/ai8j1).

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'https://thefortcity.dev/build/fonts/FontAwesome_Regular.json', function (font) {
    var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( "text", {
        font: font,

        size: 50,
        height: 10,
        curveSegments: 12,

        bevelThickness: 1,
        bevelSize: 1,
        bevelEnabled: true
    });

    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( 
        { color: 0xff0000, specular: 0xffffff }
    );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Comment: The problem i guess isn't the javascript, is your json try to pass here if isn't to Big.

Comment: @headmax i have updated my post

Comment: thank you ;) for the adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using Font Awesome. If you take a close look at your font definition file, you won't find definitions for any of the letters in `"text"` which is what you want to display. If you try something else, like :

```
/** 
   below boxes stand for: 
   - fa-volume-up [&#xf028;]
   - fa-font [&#xf031;]
   - fa-italic [&#xf033;]
   - fa-align-right [&#xf038;]
*/
var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( "   ", {
```

then it should work.
You can copy the above symbols from the [cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) and paste them into your code to check if it works.

---

As an example you can try out [this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4aOayUHq2HvXlQTgUOaH?p=info).

Comment: ohh thank you! i didn't notice that. The error disappeared but it doesn't show the text. I've tried different font so  i can use text. How can i show it on the screen? I can display .BoxGeometry fine

Comment: i've updated your question - you should position your mesh so that you can see the text - try setting (x,y,z) like `mesh.position.x = -100;`

Comment: I've tried to change the values and it still won't display. I've tried to output scene and it actually reads it but it is weird that it doesn't display. I am trying three.js with ar.js

Comment: you can check out a plunkr i've written for you in the updated version of my answer ;)